# Issue Building Rally Query that Returns Dates for Status Changes

Tags: date, rally, custom-fields

I am trying to build a rally query in the rally UI that shows the date a particular status has changed for custom fields. I can see when an item has been accepted with "AcceptedDate" but I cannot return the date a rally item has changed from a custom field. For instance -

```
(c_KanbanState = "Idea", lastupdate = beforetoday)
```

How could I accomplish this and what would the proper syntax be?

Thanks!

Comment: are you trying to do in UI or in some sdk?

Comment: In the rally UI. Great question! I'll update my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked and it appears to work for me with a little modification:

```
((c_KanbanState = "Idea") AND (LastUpdateDate >= "lastweek"))
```

Comment: You're the best! Thank you so much!